# k-means clustering on ORB features

Tags: opencv, scikit-learn, k-means, orb

I have to do image classification based on k-means clustering of ORB features. If I understood correctly from documentation, a feature is essentially a keypoint and a descriptor. I'm not sure what I should put as X when I do kmeans.fit(): in the example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html) it says that X_digits is a numpy array of Bunch objects, so I'm assuming that I should group the keypoint and the corresponding descriptor toghether and use that as the X in kmeans.fit(x).
Here's the code:

```py
@dataclass
class BOVWFeaturizer(ImgFeaturizerABC):
    number_of_features_per_image: int = 100
    vocabulary_size: int = 8
    def fit(self, images: np.ndarray, labels=None):
        orb = cv.ORB_create(self.number_of_features_per_image)
        keypoints_orb = orb.detect(images, None)
        keypoints_orb, descriptors = orb.compute(images, keypoints_orb)
        kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0)
        """
        features = ## something that groups keypoints and descriptor
        """
        kmeans.fit(features, labels)

        return self
```

I have no prior knowledge of machine learning or computer vision, so sorry if this is a really basic question

Edit: 
here's what I've tried:

```py
features = [[kp, desc] for kp, desc in zip(keypoints_orb, descriptors)]
features = [(kp, desc) for kp, desc in zip(keypoints_orb, descriptors)]
```

In both cases, the output was:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'cv2.KeyPoint'
```

I've tried converting it to an ndarray:

```py
features = np.ndarray([(kp, desc) for kp, desc in zip(keypoints_orb, descriptors)])
```

Output:

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 100
```

Am i supposed to compress both values (keypoint and descriptor) into an 1d ndarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not add keypoints to the classifier. Classification will be done only based on the descriptors, So just feed the classifier with descriptors as the input features.